# Como fazer com que o click não desloque um elemento no jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Neste **[exemplo](http://stanley.axitech.com.br/pontos-de-atendimento)** dependendo do lugar que eu clicar, a página se movimenta para alcançar o `ID` que está sendo selecionado com o click. Gostaria de impedir que a página **NÃO** se movimentasse independente do click que fosse dado.

Usei este código pois preciso pegar o `ID` desse elemento `HTML A` ...

```
$("#map li a").click(function(){

    var estado = $(this).attr("id");
    var Cestado = estado.toUpperCase();
    alert(Cestado); 

});
```

Comment: Marcos, marquei como duplicada pois acho que precisa usar `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Marcos o que precisa é http://jsfiddle.net/aumb6zd7/ mas se eu estiver errado em relação à duplicata diga pois não o quero impedir de encontrar solução para o problema...